# RadEditor Custom Tool Bar

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am trying to add some custom buttons to the tool bar, but for some reason the toolbar either get completely replace by my custom button or it does not show up at all. I basically want the default buttons as well as my custom buttons. This is the way I am creating my RadEditor

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True"/>
            <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditorControl" runat="server" ToolbarMode="RibbonBar" Skin="Silk" Width="100%">
                <SpellCheckSettings AjaxUrl="/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" />
                <Modules>
                    <telerik:EditorModule Name="RadEditorHtmlInspector" Enabled="false" />
                    <telerik:EditorModule Name="RadEditorNodeInspector" Enabled="false" />
                    <telerik:EditorModule Name="RadEditorDomInspector" Enabled="false" />
                    <telerik:EditorModule Name="RadEditorStatistics" Enabled="false" />
                </Modules>
            </telerik:RadEditor>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I've literally copy and pasted the code from [the telerik site for custom buttons](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/customtools/defaultcs.aspx), I also tried the first three but not the last one where I have to change the skin. Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

THere are many ways to define the toolbars. THe most prominent one is throug the ToolsFile. If you do not touch the editor it will use a default one, if you declare your own tools, it will not use it. So, you can take the default one and append it as desired:

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/details/default-toolsfile-xml-file-of-radeditor-for-asp-net-ajax

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-using-toolsfile.html

Of course, you can always simply declare all the tools you want in the markup or in an ASP Theme.

Yet another option is to create the tools in the code-behind after a call to EnsureToolsFileLoaded(). Let's take the code from the demo you linked and add the first line:
            RadEditor1.EnsureToolsFileLoaded();
            EditorToolGroup main = new EditorToolGroup();
            RadEditor1.Tools.Add(main);

```
        EditorTool applySizeColor = new EditorTool();
        applySizeColor.Name = "ApplySizeColor";
        applySizeColor.Text = "Apply Size and Color";
        main.Tools.Add(applySizeColor);

        EditorTool customDate = new EditorTool();
        customDate.Name = "InsertCustomDate";
        customDate.Text = "Insert Custom Date";
        main.Tools.Add(customDate);

        EditorTool reset = new EditorTool();
        reset.Text = "Reset Content";
        reset.Name = "ResetContent";
        main.Tools.Add(reset);
```

Comment: The tool bar disappear if I try that. I just did a work around where I created my own tool File and added that to the default tools file mention in your link.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the default toolbar when adding a new custom button, you should call the

RadEditor1.EnsureToolsFileLoaded() server-side method.

After that register the new custom button(s).